# How to use @JsonIdentityInfo with circular references?

Tags: java, json, jackson, circular-reference, jackson2

I am trying to use the @JsonIdentityInfo from Jackson 2 as described [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonFeatureObjectIdentity).

For testing purposes I created the following two classes:

```
public class A
{
    private B b;
    // constructor(s) and getter/setter omitted
}
public class B
{
    private A a;
    // see above
}
```

Of course, the naive approach failes:

```
@Test
public void testJacksonJr() throws Exception
{
    A a = new A();
    B b = new B(a);
    a.setB(b);
    String s = JSON.std.asString(a);// throws StackOverflowError
    Assert.assertEquals("{\"@id\":1,\"b\":{\"@id\":2,\"a\":1}}", s);
}
```

Adding `@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")` to class A and/or class B does not work either.

I was hoping that I could serialize (and later deserialize) `a` to something like this: (not too sure about the JSON though)

```
{
    "b": {
        "@id": 1,
        "a": {
            "@id": 2,
            "b": 1
        }
    }
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: This works fine for me and generates `{"@id":1,"b":{"@id":2,"a":1}}`.

Comment: Strange. I am using jackson-jr-all-2.7.4.jar and com.fasterxml.jackson.jr.ob.JSON. What JSON class have you used? With the annotation on both classes?

Comment: I just created an `ObjectMapper` and use `writeValueAsString`. (This is with your `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotations.)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It seems [jackson-jr](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jr) has a subset of Jackson's features. `@JsonIdentityInfo` must not have made the cut.

If you can use the full Jackson library, just use a standard `ObjectMapper` with the `@JsonIdentityInfo` annotation you suggested in your question and serialize your object. For example

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class A {/* all that good stuff */}

@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class B {/* all that good stuff */}
```

and then

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B(a);
a.setB(b);
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(a));
```

will generate

```
{
    "@id": 1,
    "b": {
        "@id": 2,
        "a": 1
    }
}
```

where the nested `a` is referring to the root object by its `@id`.

Comment: @ Sotirios Delimanolis Any idea how to ignore the "@id" in the json response?

Comment: @SuRa What do you mean by _ignore_? That's the point of `@JsonIdentityInfo`, to provide a property (it can have any name) that identifies the object.

Comment: While retrieving data from rest client, I am getting <<com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not instantiate value of type [simple type, class name ] from Integral number (1); no single-int-arg constructor/factory method>> exception. How to fix this? The nested "a": 1 causing the problem.

Comment: @SuRa I'm not sure about that. The `a` should be a regular property `getA` and `setA`. You'd have to provide a full example, consider asking a new question.

Comment: @SuRa looks like you want JsonIgnore annotation

Answer (score 3):

There are several approaches to solve this circular references or infinite recursion issues. This [link](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) explain in details each one.  I have solved my issues including @JsonIdentityInfo annotation above each related entity, although @JsonView is more recent and may it's a better solution depending of your scenery.

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property = "id")
```

Or using an IntSequenceGenerator implementation:

```
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.IntSequenceGenerator.class)
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable 
...
```

Answer (score -1):

In some cases, it can be necessary to annotate the *Id Property* with **@JsonProperty("id")**

For example, in my case, this made my application run correctly.